# Node JS, express, Mongoose, nested queries

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, express

I have a set of nested queries with express/mongoose, pretty much like so:

```
app.get(..., function(...) {

   Schema1.query(..., function(..., res1) {

      for ( var key in res1 ) {
           Schema2.query(..., function(..., res2) {
             data[key].appendedAttribute = res2.somedata;
            });
      }

      res.render(..., data);
   });
```

});

Which doesnt work, that is, appendedAttribute is never appended to the dataset.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not how asynchronous programming works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`after`](https://github.com/Raynos/after.js)

```
app.get(..., function(...) {
    Schema1.query(..., function(..., res1) {
        var cb = after(Object.keys(res1).length, function () {
            res.render(..., data);    
        });

        for (var key in res1) {
            Schema2.query(..., function(..., res2) {
                data[key].appendedAttribute = res2.somedata;
                cb();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Basically you must only fire the `res.render` call after the second query has finished.

Comment: Aren't you suppose to call cb() only after all the queries get executed..? (thus just once)

Comment: @alessioalex `cb` has to called `n` times. before it continues. the n is the first parameter to `after`. i.e. the amount Schema2 queries he makes.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Step](https://github.com/creationix/step):

```
app.get(..., function(...) {
  var data;
  Step(
    function first_query() {
      Schema1.query(...,this);
    },
    function multiple_queries(err, res1) {
      for (var key in res1) {
        Schema2.query(..., function(..., res2) {
          data[key].appendedAttribute = res2.somedata;
          this.parallel(); // make sure callback gets executed only after all the queries are executed
        });
      }     
    },
    function render() {
      res.render(..., data);
    }
  );
});
```